# What is wrong with this jQuery syntax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, syntax

This code keeps throwing an "unexpected token' error, but I can't figure out what is wrong with it.  Any clues would be great.

```
function addComment() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'/add/comment/id',
        type:'POST',
        data.JSON.stringify({'Text':$('#comment_text').val()}),
        contentType:'application/json; charset=utf8',
        processData:false,
        success:function(data){
            $('#comments').prepend(data.comment.Text);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: data : JSON.stringify({'Text':$('#comment_text').val()}),

Comment: oh man, that's embarrassing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data: JSON.stringify({'Text':$('#comment_text').val()}),
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is on this line:

```
data.JSON.stringify({'Text':$('#comment_text').val()}),
```

The unexpected token is the period (`.`) after `data`.

Instead of a period (`.`), you need a colon (`:`) after `data`, like so:

```
data: JSON.stringify({'Text':$('#comment_text').val()}),
```

Note that **you don't need `JSON.stringify`** here. As @pst pointed out, jQuery does that for you anyways.

```
data: {
  'Text': $('#comment_text').val()
},
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data.JSON.stringify({'Text':$('#comment_text').val()})
```

should be:

```
data: JSON.stringify({'Text':$('#comment_text').val()})
```

Comment: @MFB data can be an object or string. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ Best to let jQuery do the JSONing, since not all browsers have native `JSON.stringify` support

Comment: @CameronMartin the object will be transformed into key=value pairs not JSON

Comment: @Musa oh yes of course, my bad. A url-encoded query string makes much more sense in this situation than JSON.

Comment: @CameronMartin JSON makes it easy for me because I can throw it straight at my database, but I'm looking for an easy way to convert the string instead.

Comment: What database are you using? CouchDb?

Comment: using Mongodb and Python.. nice combo but right now having trouble making a dict out of the query string :(